# Does anyone know of an embedded blog engine for Java/the JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

I'm working on a "yard sale sign" type application for a company. They are very conscientious about response times and page speed, so the application is being written on the JVM.

They would like to have a blog section of the site, which brings me to a crossroads. At this point in time, they are *not* looking for hyper advanced features; the requirements are post entries, full text search w/fuzzy matching, comments and moderation.

I love WordPress, but it's a little out of scope to integrate that into the site.

Ideal answer is if someone knows of an embeddable blog engine for the JVM or Java, but I'd like to hear anyone's take on alternatives.

Thanks SO, as always!

Comment: A quick google of "blog engine Java" seems to show several promising hits. Did you try that?

Comment: Of course! I'm looking for something embeddable and tiny. None of the Google search results i'm scrolling through do that and tend more to be full blown CMSs.

Comment: It is a simple matter to take "full blown" product and turn off the functionality that you don't require.  (Besides, one has to question the company's priorities if they are saying that the blog section has to have fast response times / page speeds.  Surely, it is not "core" functionality.  Where's the business case for a blindingly fast Blog section?)

Comment: the business case is 'showing off'. I think I'm going to have to roll my own :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're rolling our own... I think my company will end up open-sourcing it. Details to follow!

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm looking at needing some similar functionality and am interested in what you've developed.

Comment: Unfortunately no :/ We ended up writing it, but never open sourced it.

BTW, if you can use a non-java solution, check out Gollum on github. It's probably not as "Web-scale" as a java solution, but it's pretty cool.